# Java Stream Debugger is not available for IntelliJ IDEA newer versions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream, intellij-plugin

I just run into a useful plugin to debug Java Streams called [Java Stream Debugger](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9696-java-stream-debugger/versions). However, it is not available for the newer IntelliJ IDEA versions. The interesting things is, it is seen on a tutorial that was published 3 moths ago on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kon1DGwbtzg) page.

How can I install Java Stream Debugger (I tried to install from disk, but not possible)?

Is there any good alternatives for debugging Streams in IntelliJ IDEA? I see [Reactive Streams](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20201-reactive-streams/versions), but not sure if it can be used for Java Stream?

Note: My IntelliJ IDEA version is **2022.3 (Ultimate)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a comment from JetBrains team: since 2017.3 the feature is available out of the box (you should not install the plugin anymore).

Comment: Yes amigo, I enabled it from Plugins > Installed section to debug Java streams.